# Angular check FormControl Validators list during testing

Tags: jasmine, angular-test

I have a `FormControl` which dynamically adds or removes validators depending on the state of other controls.  In my `.spec.ts` file, what is the right way to iterate through all the validators to check for specific values?

Specifically I want to verify whether there is or is not a `Validators.required` element present, and whether there is or is not a `Validators.minLength` element.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the pseudo code for the test should look like this:

1. Ensure that neither `Validators.required` nor `Validators.minLength` are present
2. Do something to add `Validators.required`
3. Test that only `Validators.required` is present
4. Do something to add `Validators.minLength`
5. Test that both validators are present
6. Do something to remove `Validators.required`
7. Test that only `Validators.minLength` is present
8. Do something to remove `Validators.minLength`
9. Test that neither validators are present

Based on your specification above you only need to check for those two validators. If you need to test for more than two, then you probably want to programmatically iterate through all of the interesting validators to check both for their presence and their absence. Optionally, you can also test for interactions between them.

Comment: My problem is I'm not seeing a property on `FormControl` that let's me check what validatiors are set.